# How do you access the updated pose location data for posed objects through python scripting?

Tags: python, scripting

I want to be able to access the posed xyz location data for objects parented to an armature.

I can do this for bones:

```
bpy.data.objects["spine_armature"].pose.bones['Bone.007'].matrix.to_euler()
```

but how do I do that for the objects listed under the armature?
[image: Armature objects]

So far the location I have accessed for object location doesn't seem to change when I change the pose - like it is the original un-posed location.

How would I access the posed object location data by name? (not by currently active object)

---

Edit: the original title still stands, but I could be looking in the wrong place for the pose location data.

When I access

```
bpy.data.objects["spine_armature"].children
```

it does give the children of spine_armature, but the vector data doesn't seem to change after the pose has changed.

I'm looking to find the new posed location of an object.
The location data for a posed object doesn't seem to change.
What data changes that has the new location data?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!
I was searching for something else Python and came across the beginning of what I needed in the "How to get frame-by-frame object location in Blender 2.8+" post.

As the answer there says

> the object origin "stays" at its original position

Thanks to:

- [How to get frame-by-frame object location in Blender 2.8+](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/216149/how-to-get-frame-by-frame-object-location-in-blender-2-8)
- [Error Setting new vertice coordinate values in python - 'BMVertSeq' object does not support item assignment](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/227647/error-setting-new-vertice-coordinate-values-in-python-bmvertseq-object-does)
- [How to fix outdated internal index table in an addon](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31738/how-to-fix-outdated-internal-index-table-in-an-addon)

I have put together some code that gives me the position of an object relative to it's resting pose position.
If I wanted the absolute position, I could add the two points.

In the code *Vert_8_3* is the object in question, a single vert object

```
context = bpy.context
vertebre_obj = context.scene.objects['Vert_8_3']
depsgraph = context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_object(vertebre_obj, depsgraph)

if hasattr(bm.verts, "ensure_lookup_table"): 
    bm.verts.ensure_lookup_table()

vertebre_data = bm.verts[0].co.xyz
```

*bm.verts[0]* throws the error `IndexError: BMElemSeq[index]: outdated internal index table, run ensure_lookup_table() first` if the following is not added before accessing the location data:

```
if hasattr(bm.verts, "ensure_lookup_table"): 
    bm.verts.ensure_lookup_table()
```

Comment: If the order of the vertices is not important (and clearly it isn't if there's just one), you could use `bm.verts[:][0]` instead - to copy the list and then access it without an error. Of course use the trick with caution: the error is there to save you from [heisenbugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug) based on semi-random vertex ordering if the lookup is not ensured. As well as if you have a lot of vertices (but still don't care about their order), you can use `next(v for v in bm.verts)` to get one without generating an entire list of them.

Comment: Thanks; I actually ran into the vertex order issue when trying to sum up the distances on an object - turned on the index display and edge length - displaying weird results even though the order seems ok - but that's another unrelated issue :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import bpy

for oj in bpy.data.objects["spine_armature"].children:
    print(oj.location)
```